# Import/Export MySQL Database

Tags: phpmyadmin

While exporting MySQL Database, I ***DIDN'T*** select:

***Add/Drop Database Option***

So, now while I try to import the database, it says "***No database found***" for importing. 
There are no customization  available for importing in phpMyAdmin.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to ask then in that case you need to create a new database first with the name same as the old database and then import the **.sql** file into the newly created database.

Comment: Yeah but I have more that 40 databases and you know who knows the name? I mean, its a server transfer with a lot data.